# java - Loop optimization on int array

Tags: java, loops, optimization

I would like to know, which is fast way to write/read in an **int** array.

Here my **Java code:** I have three **int** arrays, two in read access and one **int** array in write access.

```
for(int j = h20 ; j < h21 ; j++){
    for(int i = w20 ; i < w21 ; i++){
        if( int_color == arr3[j*h31 + i] )  continue; //condition 
        arr1[(j+decY)*w11 + i+decX] = arr2[j*w21 + i];      
    }   
}
```

My code is a classic 2D array loop, there are just one special condition to check.

Is it other way to write this code to decrease processing time?

Thx.

Comment: "_Is it other way to write this code to decrease processing time?_" since you need both `i` and `j`, even if you can merge your loops, you still need `h21 * w21` iteration. SO it won't change much. Now, based on the logic (we don't have all the data here) maybe you can simplify this.

Comment: Unless you find a way to reduce the number of operations in the calculation of the indices, I'd say this is as optimized as it gets. You could do all operations that rely on `j` *before* you enter second loop, so that those values have to be calculated only once per inner loop.

Comment: You should invert the condition of the if statement and remove `continue`.

Comment: No, is impossible to change logic, I know problem is the condition which is a barrier to global memory copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reduce the amount of calculations, if you separate them by variables. In your case, any calculation that relies on `j` alone doesn't have to be inside the inner loop because the result won't change for the rest of the loop. Instead, calculate the values *outside* and only use the result in the inner loop.

```
for(int j = h20 ; j < h21 ; j++){
    int tmp1 = j*h31;
    int tmp2 = (j+decY)*w11 + decX;
    int tmp3 = j*w21;

    // j won't change inside here, so you can simply use the precalculated values
    for(int i = w20 ; i < w21 ; i++){
        if( int_color == arr3[tmp1 + i] )  continue; //condition 
        arr1[tmp2 + i] = arr2[tmp3 + i];      
    }   
}
```

**Edit:** If you want to reduce this even more, you could rewrite the calculation for `tmp2`:

```
(j+decY)*w11 + decX ==> j*w11 + decY*w11 + decX
```

Then, you could extract the `decY*w11 + decX` into its own variable outside the first loop.

```
int tmp0 = decY*w11 + decX;
for(int j = h20 ; j < h21 ; j++){
    int tmp1 = j*h31;
    int tmp2 = j*w11 + tmp0;
    int tmp3 = j*w21;

    // j won't change inside here, so you can simply use the precalculated values
    for(int i = w20 ; i < w21 ; i++){
        if( int_color == arr3[tmp1 + i] )  continue; //condition 
        arr1[tmp2 + i] = arr2[tmp3 + i];      
    }   
}
```

But this will save you only one addition per iteration, so I don't think it's worth the extra effort.

Comment: Yes, you right, I forgot this way. I am not specialist in JAVA, I thought expert method as iterator or other way focused on JAVA methods.

Comment: Your optimizations seem to be alright, but they're probably useless as the JIT compiler knows these tricks, too.

Answer (score 1):

Removing calculations, especially multiplications might help.

For arr3 this would be:

```
final int icolor = int_color;
final int ix3 = h20 + w20;
final int dx3 = h31 + h21 - h20;

for (int j = h20; j < h21; ++j) {
    for (int i = w20 ; i < w21 ; ++i) {
        assert ix3 == j*h31 + i;
        if (icolor != arr3[ix3]) {
            arr1[(j+decY)*w11 + i+decX] = arr2[j*w21 + i];
        }
        ++ix3;
    }
    ix3 += dx3;
}
```

Whether this is really worthwile one needs to test.

Depending on the frequency of the condition, one might think of using `System.arraycopy` for consecutive ranges of i.

Comment: your `ix3` was `j * h31 + i`, you can't evaluate it outside of the loop, you need `i` and `j`. Here you are checking each time the same value.

Comment: @AxelH right, I had forgotten to increase ix3 in the inner loop. Corrected